# Automatic inputs into a c program from a text file

Tags: c, io

Is it possible in C , to input data from a text file automatically.If not in C , then is it possible in other languages.
For eg: i am building a tree and each node of the tree is supposed to contain 1000 most popular English words.Now instead of providing manual inputs , i was wondering if i could do it automatically by pasting all the words in a text file and then using some operation to store them into each node one by one. I only want to know if it's possible , i'll work out the rest , if it is.If not in C,then is it possible in any other language.

Comment: @nos is it applicable for the example i wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible to do that, [C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) [does](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/) [file I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) and really that's all your asking. What you need to do is open the text file where you stored the words, loop 1000 times reading from the file. Since you know the number of nodes in your tree you can statically allocate 1000 nodes, or you can do it as you read (`malloc`) dynamically, but make sure you remember to free it when you're done.

There's dozens of examples online, but here's a 2 second overview:

```
char word[100]; // longest word you have in the file +1
FILE * fp = fopen("words.txt", "r"); // you'll need to open the file for reading

for(int count = 0; count < 1000; count++){
    fgets(word, 100, fp); // read each word in
    // do whatever to populate a node
}

fclose(fp); // you shold close it when you're done
```

Answer (score 1):

## Yes you can

The truth is, it is (mostly) C language code compiled to machine code, that is handling your Hard-disk, your OS, the memory and all the virtual files you see on your desktop.

the header `stdio.h` contains functions for reading and writing to files.

Some of the API functions and structures are:

`FILE`, `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `freopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fread()`, `rewind()`, `fseek()`, `ftell()`, `fgets()`, `fputs()`, `fprintf()`, `fscanf()` - google them and their uses/usage.

Comment: Ha! +1 just for the big bold answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I had left all the File part of C,I decided i'll learn it when the time comes.Guess the time has come.Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the time seems to have come @user1946033